# Zooming in and out messes up the alignment

Tags: html, css, web

I have been given an assignment to make a marksheet using div. I am new and this is my first project in which I am using inline CSS. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16EhVQRTYA4DEqDbsMlROeIVbEx3Sw06Q/view?usp=sharing) is the code if you want to take a look.

And this is what happens when I zoom in or out:

at 100% (Looks perfect)
[image]

At 110%
[image]

At 125%

[image]

At 90%

[image]

It may be because of error in my calculations of pixels and I checked but I can't find where is the problem. And I think the remarks div could be the cause because of float attribute i guess.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: heyy can't you use table tag?

Comment: Here are a few tips if you are an absolute beginner in web development. try to use at least internal CSS with the help of class or id. And use codepen, jsfiddle like platforms to put your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:1600px; background-color:999999; margin:0 auto;">
```

To

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color:999999; margin:0 auto;">
```

Now go change the width of other divs, and do not use Pixels as a measure, simply use %

Remember the final width of all divs should be 100%
For example

```
div 1 = 30%
div 2 = 50%
div 3 = 20%
```